# ui.bootstrap.typeahead: how to combine $http with debounce

Tags: javascript, c#, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, rxjs

I'd like to take advantage of ui.bootstrap.typeahead because it is excellent. I'm implementing a search of a database that could contain millions of users, so I would really like to be able to debounce keystrokes in the search box before making a call to $http. Otherwise every keystroke will result in a search, and early keystrokes will generate slower searches than later keystrokes, resulting in a clunky user experience.

My current effort, which doesn't work, looks like this:

**JavaScript:**

```
angular.module("mycontrollers").controller("myCtrl", [
    "$scope", "$http", "rx", "localisationService", "close", function ($scope, $http, rx, localisationService, close) {
        var culture = localisationService.getCulture();
        function getUsersObservable(val) {
            return rx.Observable
                .fromPromise($http.get("/api/" + culture + "/usersearch", { params: { userName: val } }))
                .map(function (response) {
                    return response.data;
                });
        }
        $scope.close = close;
        $scope.$createObservableFunction("getUsers")
            .debounce(400)
            .filter(function (val) {
                return val.length > 0;
            })
            .flatMapLatest(getUsersObservable)
            .subscribe();
    }
]);
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="the-user" localised-text-key="TheUser"></label>
    <input type="text" id="the-user" ng-model="userId" uib-typeahead="user for user in getUsers($viewValue)" typeahead-loading="loadingUsers" class="form-control" />
</div>
```

**Server Side:**

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get(string userName)
{
    var users = await _modelContext.Users.Where(u => u.UserName.Contains(userName)).OrderBy(u => u.UserName).Select(u => u.UserName).Take(20).ToArrayAsync();
    return Ok(users);
}
```

The input is being debounced correctly; the `rx.observable` at the start of the JavaScript is returning the search results as an array of strings, and debouncing the input correctly. What I'm not sure how to do is to package the results up into a promise that can be interpreted correctly by ui.bootstrap.typeahead.

Comment: Have you tried using [Async Validators](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/angularjs/3979/form-validation/22099/async-validators#t=201610190950349255524)?

Comment: Thanks for this -- I wasn't aware of these, so it's good to see that they're available. In this case it doesn't really do what I need, as it doesn't offer any support for debouncing (which means sending a call to the server after 400ms, rather than on each keystroke). What I'm really after is a way to make the Angular rx debounce work well together with the Angular UI Bootstrap typeahead functionality.

Comment: When I wrote the example I took an existing code I worked on and simplified it. In the original I used the `_.debouce` function from the underscore library.

Comment: oh, and you can also use `ng-model-options` to setup a debouce for when the value updates. the docs cover that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I totally missed it in the docs

> ng-model-options $ - Options for ng-model (see [ng-model-options directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions)). Currently supports the debounce and getterSetter options.

So the directive allows you to attach options to it's `ng-model` very much as plain ol' Angular does.

So you can then use it to set a debouce to your model value, and then call a function through the `ng-change` directive.

```
<input type="text" id="the-user" 
    ng-model="userId" 
    ng-model-options="{'debounce': 500}" 
    ng-change="sendHttpAfterDebounce()"
    uib-typeahead="user for user in getUsers($viewValue)" typeahead- 
    loading="loadingUsers" 
    class="form-control" />
```

Now your function (`sendHttpAfterDebounce`) will run 500 milliseconds after you're done typing.