# AngularJS - Typeahead Asynchronous data

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, angular-ui-bootstrap, typeahead, debouncing

I'm using Typeahead bootstrap with anguarJS to fetch data from rails api, the problem is that the request get data every time I type a letter in the input, I want te perform and decrease a little bit the number of request and debounce it to make a match between what is typed and the data retrieved.

here is the controller :

```
 getSpecificationTemplatesNames = (value) ->
    dataStore.post DATASTORE_CACHE_KEY, "/specification_templates/specification_templates_names",{post: {search: value}},(data) ->
      $scope.names = data.templates.names


  # --- WATCHER ---

  $scope.$watch 'specificationTemplate.name', (value)  ->
    $scope.specificationDisabledForm = !value
    getSpecificationTemplatesNames(value)
```

and here is the haml part :

```
 .col-md-8
          %input.specification-template-name{ type: 'text', name: 'name', typeahead: 'name for name in names | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:15', typeahead_wait_ms:'2000',
                        ng: { model: 'specificationTemplate.name', disabled: 'contractPeriod.isArchived()' }}
```

In the ui-bootstrap doc example version  ***0.12.1***, the async loading is triggered through typeahead="address for address in getLocation($viewVlue) but they don't use a watcher on the model. Their getLocations method is my getSpecificationTemplatesNames method.

can some one help to perform this and transform with me the code and use the typeahead-wait-ms option correctly using coffeescript!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ui.bootstrap.typeahead: how to combine $http with debounce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40126717/ui-bootstrap-typeahead-how-to-combine-http-with-debounce)

Comment: a little bit different @JonSenchyna

Comment: Have you tried using `ng-model-options="{'debounce': ...}"`?

Comment: there is no ng-model-option in the doc ! http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/versioned-docs/0.12.1/#/typeahead

Comment: That is because it is not part of `typeahead`, but part of `angularJS` itself: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the solution i found, use promise :

haml part :

```
 %input.specification-template-name{ type: 'text', name: 'name', typeahead: 'name for name in getSpecificationTemplatesNames($viewValue) | limitTo:15', typeahead_wait_ms:'1000',
                        ng: { model: 'specificationTemplate.name', disabled: 'contractPeriod.isArchived()' }}
```

angularjs controller :

```
$scope.getSpecificationTemplatesNames = (value) ->
    $q( (resolve, reject) ->
     dataStore.post DATASTORE_CACHE_KEY, "/specification_templates/specification_templates_names",{post: {search: value}},(data) ->
        resolve( data.templates.names || [] )
    )

  # --- WATCHER ---

  $scope.$watch 'specificationTemplate.name', (value)  ->
    $scope.specificationDisabledForm = !value
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you are not defining `typeahead-wait-ms` properly.  You have underscores in the attribute name, rather than dashes.

Additionally, you can use `ng-model-options="{'debounce': ...}"` to add a debounce to the updating of your model.

Comment: In fact that code is working properly because in the project we customize the syntaxe and we use coffeescript that's why the underscore work

Comment: and the problem is that the request to server is lunched every time I type a character in the input , so what I want is decrease the number of request like they do in the doc : http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/versioned-docs/0.12.1/#/typeahead